# Errors build gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After adding the apply plugin: '`com.google.gms.google-services`'. I  am getting  following errors

> An error occurs after sync.ERROR: No such property:
>   applicationVariants for class: java.lang.String

Open File.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.8@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
}

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you please provide your comple build.gradle

Comment: its all build.gradle (mobile:app)

Answer (score -2):

Try to add 
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` 
and delete the line with "apply plugin".
It should work.